# Does selling gainers and loser lots of stock trigger Wash Sale?

Tags: taxes, employee-stock-options, wash-sale

My employers gives me stock compensation every month. There is no day in the year I can sell my losing lots of stock without triggering the wash sale rule.

Can I sell winnings and losing lots of stocks in the same transaction to offset (but not eliminate completely) the gains of that transaction? Is that a wash sale as well?

Comment: What country's tax laws are you interested in? Please add a country tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you seems to be "stuck" in a wash sale cycle, but all that means is that the *tax benefit* is deferred until you ultimately close out your position. The loss is just shifted to the cost basis of the most recent purchase. The loss is not "gone" forever.

However, the *purpose* of the wash sale rule is to prevent tax loss harvesting by deferring tax losses until your position is closed, but that does not seem to be your intent. I would talk with a tax attorney that deals with wash sale rules and see if there are precedents that would indicate that regularly acquired lots that prevent any 30-day window would be exempt.

But in the end, all you're doing is *deferring* the loss; you'll be able to claim it eventually.